# How can I load the resources of my game made with Phaser 3 that is inside a project with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, phaser-framework

I have a project of a website, it is a SPA with **ReactJS**, in which I am using **Phaser 3** to make my game. Actually I am migrating the project that previously was in Angular Framework. The problem I am facing is that when trying to load the images of my game in the preload **function**, I cannot access the path where the images of the Game are stored. Doing this did not give me problems with Angular.

I don't know if this is a problem with the way ReactJS uses its components and how it loads React images.

The Game itself is not a **React** Component, it is only a separate module I export within the component that will render the game view.

In the Angular project I did This:

[image]

1. Is the component where the game is rendered
2. Is the scene from the image is loaded
3. Is the code for load the image
4. Is where the image is stored

It works correctly! but using Angular.

In the other hand using **ReactJS** I'm getting problems loading the same images of the same game from the assets folder of the reactJS project.

[image]

1. Is the **react** component where the game is rendered
2. Is where I configure the game that is in other JS file (Is not a react component)
3. Is Where Game is rendered
4. Is the scene from the image is loaded
5. Is where the image is stored

Result:

[image]

I must say that I have tried several routes without success.

[image]

```
preload() {
   this.load.image('background', 'assets/games/blaster-x/images/background.png');       
}

preload() {
   this.load.image('background', '../../assets/games/blaster-x/images/background.png');       
}
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, code or logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

React uses a different style for file loaders of assets.

```
import backgroundImage from ‘src/assets/games/images/background.png’;

...

this.load.image(‘background’, backgroundImage);
```

Comment: I think that if it was transformed into a React JS component it could be done that way.

Comment: It not a react thing but the webpack configuration underlying react-scripts. I should have asked, are you using CRA or your own webpack config? https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Comment: For practical purposes, I am using CRA but maybe in the future I will need a custom configuration.

Comment: I would only eject for educational purposes. It helps to know what does what in the build process behind the scenes.

Comment: This doesn't work.  https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/3897

Comment: @Steve You probably have other issues in your configuration. The most obvious is the issue of that ticket which uses url-loader and webpack. I only tested the above with react-scripts. Just change the file loader behavior in babel to fix the issue, either by replacing the loader or doing the inline limit solution.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was package.json configuration that I didn't notice (public is the folder to place your files)

```
"staticFiles": {
        "staticPath": "public",
        "watcherGlob": "**"
    }
```

Comment: What is `staticFiles`? could you specify a link where to refer to get accurate information?

Comment: I'm using ParcelJS and this is the plugin https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy/v/2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching and the thing is that ReactJS JXS uses a different way to import its images into its components.

```
import image1 from './images/image1.jpg';
<img src={image1} />
```

Or

```
<img src={ require('./images/image1.jpg') } />
```

In the case of my game made with Phaser 3 to access the resources from the scenes, it works only if I move all my assets into the public folder of the ReactJS project.

More info here:

https://phaser.discourse.group/t/this-load-image-file-path-not-working/1566/11

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in the production build version of Create React App, phaser 3 images weren't loading. The solution, which I found [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/3897#issuecomment-739247579) was to put

`IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT=1`

in an .env file at the root of the project. That causes webpack to handle the loading of images differently.

Answer (score 0):

This example can be used in react or whatever if you want to add Dinamic Url with import

About import: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta

About new Url : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

import.meta.url is a native ESM feature that exposes the current module's URL. Combining it with the native URL constructor, we can obtain the full, resolved URL of a static asset using relative path from a JavaScript module:

Phaser Code:

```
preload() {
 // Pure Js code: new URL ()
 const urlImg = new URL(`../img/${arenaImg.urlArena}`, import.meta.url).href
 this.load.image('SelectArena', urlImg)
}
```